# Запуск таймера на сервере

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите пожалуйста как на php или javascript реализовать запуск таймера на сервере ?

К примеру в интерфейсе есть кнопка по ее нажатию запустить удаления файла через 15 минут ?

Comment: если на пыхе, то мне видится так: занести имена удаляемых файлов в таблицу с меткой времени, а крон периодически проглядывающий эту таблицу удаляет файлы по метке времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще такие действия лучше делать через **cron**, записать php файл на удаление и запустить когда тебе необходимо. А так можно и через js

```
setTimeout(deleteFiles, 900000); // 1000 - это одна секунда
```

deleteFiles твоя функция удаления

```
    deleteFiles(){
    const fs = require('fs')
    try {
        fs.unlinkSync('file.txt'); //Можешь добавить папку dirname/
        console.log('Файл успешно удален');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
    }
```

Если тебе нужно удалить все файлы в папке, то лучше сначала записать все файлы в массив и в цикле удалить их, но для безопасности лучше отправить запрос на удаление в php.

Comment: Только речь идёт о PHP..

Comment: В вопросе php или javascript.

Comment: `javascript` в вопросе только потому что "в интерфейсе есть кнопка".

Comment: Можно удалить файлы на js и на php. Там нет "и", только "или". Таймер можно сделать только на js...

Comment: а если страницу закроют через 20 секунд?

Comment: Вместо крона на сервере можно использовать внешние крон сервисы. Хотя это конечно и дополнительная морока. Но это может быть аналогом JS дерганья серверного скрипта по расписанию.